# Did Ravana write any books?

Tags: ravana

Consider the following statement about Ravana from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravana#Iconography):

> **Ravana is also depicted as the author of the Ravana Samhita, a book on
>    Hindu astrology and book Arka Prakasham; book on Siddha medicine and treatment** . Ravana possessed a thorough knowledge of Siddha and political science. He is said to have possessed the nectar of immortality, which was stored inside his belly, thanks to a celestial boon by Brahma.

It is clearly saying that Ravana wrote two books: **Ravana Samhita**, a book on Hindu astrology and **Arka Prakasham**, book on Siddha medicine and treatment.

Is it true that Ravana is author of those two books or any other books?

Comment: Well some people even say that the book Lal Kitab (which also deals with easy-to-do astrological remedies) too has some connection with him.

Comment: Maybe my comment is not directly related to the Q, still just wish to share that 'Shiva Tandava' stotra has been written by Ravana.

Comment: @Rickross no that's kaali kitab or ravana samhita

Comment: Both Lal Kitab and Kaali Kitab are written by Raavan, and is not Vedic but Tantric and has shortcuts of various problems. Vedic astrology is written by Sage Parashar, father of Veda Vyasa and speaker of Vishnu Purana

Comment: All Tantra comes from Shiva and Ravana was one of his biggest worshipper, as seen in "Shiva Tandava strotram"

Comment: @Father no laal kitab is a hoax. Its written by a person called roop chand joshi in Punjab. It's in urdu script. He was an atheist and he made this to ridicule the hindus.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Lal Kitab is pretty popular among astrologers and Ravan Samhita among Tantrics. No one knows if Lal Kitab works or not, people are foolish superstitious anyways, its Kaliyuga :/

Answer (score 5):

There is hearsay about texts written by him.

There is one ancient tantric text which directly claims authorship by rAvana is [uddisha tantram](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/m/book/details/uddish-tantram-of-lankesh-ravan-NZI909/).

So this is an important text in tantra literature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there was any writing system developed during Treta Yuga. Everything was communicated orally.

Comment: Can you please elaborate along with referrences. The word "wrote" in the question does not mean literally writing on some thing like paper or leaves. I mean whether they are attributed to Ravana in any scripture.